# How to filter Eloquent query which include "orWhereHas" and "OrWhereIn"?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query in Eloquent which I want to filter by dates but having a "WhereHas" or a "WhereIn" doesn't filter them anymore. How can I solve my issue?

```
    public static function filterForTransactions(Request $request, MarketAgreement $v_teleco, AgreementEnergia $v_energia) {

        $v_teleco = $v_teleco->newQuery();

                    $v_teleco->where('user_id_inversor', \Auth::user()->id)
                    ->orWhereHas('market_transaction', function($query){
                        $query->where('user_id_subaccount', \Auth::user()->id);
                    })
                    ->orWhereIn('user_id', [$ids]);

        if ($request->has('from') && $request->has('to') && $request->input('from') != null && $request->input('to') != null) {

            $from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->from)
            ->startOfDay()
            ->toDateTimeString();


            $to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->to)
            ->endOfDay()
            ->toDateTimeString();

                
            $v_teleco->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to]);

        }

        return $v_teleco->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a few things to mention about your code

```php
public static function filterForTransactions(Request $request, MarketAgreement $v_teleco, AgreementEnergia $v_energia)
    {
        /** @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $v_teleco */
        $v_teleco = $v_teleco->newQuery();
        // when you want to modify builder object you need to overwrite it
        $v_teleco = $v_teleco->where('user_id_inversor', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhereHas('market_transaction', function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id_subaccount', \Auth::user()->id);
            })
            ->orWhereIn('user_id', [$ids]); // where do you get $ids?

        if ($request->has('from') && $request->has('to') && $request->input('from') && $request->input('to')) {
            $from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->from)
                ->startOfDay()
                ->toDateTimeString();
            $to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->to)
                ->endOfDay()
                ->toDateTimeString();
            // same here
            $v_teleco = $v_teleco->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to]);
        }

        return $v_teleco->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
    }
```

this way it looks fine so if it still doesn't work please provide more details

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying so late. Filters still not responding.

Comment: i got `$ids` from `$agentes = UsersAccount::where('user_id_responsible', \Auth::user()->id)->get()`; and `foreach($agentes as $agente){ array_push($ids, $agente->user_id_subaccount); }`

Comment: @XQUJAGGER to clarify and check selection logic: your request getting models (where current user is investor *or* have transaction *or* `user_id` in selected `$ids`) right? and what results do you get: extra or less than you expect? please update question

Comment: Correct. And this works perfectly. The problem is the filters that come from outside (the dates)

Comment: @XQUJAGGER i've tested this code - it works fine, try log `$from` and `$to` values if they parsed correct and goes in right order from frontend